# How to attach data to an error

Tags: error, fa1.2

The [FA1.2 standard](https://gitlab.com/tzip/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-7/tzip-7.md#transfer) specifies that the `NotEnoughAllowance` error should contain a `nat: required, nat: present` pair. How do I attach this kind of data to a `failwith` call?

I am writing the token contract in PascaLIGO.

Comment: Should it just be included in the error string somehow? Like this?
`failwith("NotEnoughAllowance: required: 100, present: 0");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, LIGO does not support failing with an arbitrary type like a tuple or record. However you can [embed Michelson](https://ligolang.org/docs/advanced/embedded-michelson) to fail with the tuple.